# Ajax is not called when form submitted from PHP page

Tags: php, ajax

**HTML page**

```
<form name="frm_add" id="frm_add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" >
    <input type="file" name="img01" id="img01"> 
    <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Add Data">
</form>
```

**.js page**

```
$(function() {
    $("#frm_add input, #frm_add select, #frm_add textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            //alert("It's here 001");

            $.ajax({
                url: "./add_p.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(this),
                dataType: "JSON",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
            })
        },
    });
});
```

When I try to submit form, Ajax is not called on .js page and thus add_p.php is not called.

But if I declare action and method properties in form then add_p.php page is directly called and data are processed and inserted into database table without any issue.

```
<form name="frm_add" id="frm_add" action="add_p.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I checked all type of syntax and spelling errors but they seem ok and also read many things on internet but problem is still not resolved.

below alert is called if it is above Ajax but Ajax is not called.

```
alert("It's here 001");
```

Comment: I think you should point your validator to `$('#frm_add')` and not the elements...

Comment: is there any error in your browser console?

Comment: How your form is getting submitted? your HTML code does not include submit button?

Comment: Don't you have to set validation rules for the inputs? (https://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/)

Comment: @urfusion, no error in browser console.

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar, i didn't mention submit button to keep question as small as possible but now I have added it in my question.

Comment: @OfirBaruch, yes bootstrap validation is mentioned on HTML page and  working fine.

Comment: Are you supposed to be targeting the submit button? The documentation appears to specifically exclude it.

Comment: @Terminus, can you please clarify what you are saying so I can make necessary changes here...

Comment: When selecting elements with jQuery, reactiveraven's example specifically filters out inputs of type submit. Why aren't you doing that?

Comment: @Raphioly-San, can you please clarify what you are saying so I can reply you properly...

Comment: @Terminus, I just did like reactiveraven's example but still no luck... I guess Ajax part is not executed but not sure why... also is this part 'data: new FormData(this),' correct?

Comment: data: new FormData(this), -> data: $form.serialize()

Comment: @OfirBaruch, after using serialize, it now displays add_p.php in browser console.. so I guess Ajax is called but I am not able to even echo static data on add_p.php to confirm that add_p.php page is accessed...

Comment: @KAhir use the developer console's network tab and filter by xhr. That'll let you see the request and response info

Comment: Open your chrome, mouse right click on the page and choose "Inspect" (or F12). You'll have some tabs, among them: "Console" and "Network". Choose network, then - submit your HTML form, a new row will appear 'p_add.php'. Take a screenshot and share the output with us.